# Transfer table from Ms-Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ado, transfer

I don't have much experience with SQL Server, I use it currently to run some simple queries, and I link to SQL tables from Access where I have all my heavy queries. My goal is to run all of my queries in Access daily and then at the end write the finished tables up to SQL where my Access front end will read them (versus keeping them in my Access backend).

I've tried messing around with the code below to try and figure out how to do this, but I'm stuck at the driver and I can't find any references on how to do this with just a single table. Let's call it "PO_STATUS_TBL"

```vb
Public Sub ADOtest()

   Dim ADOConn As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim ADOCom As New ADODB.Command


   On Error Resume Next

   ADOConn.ConnectionString = "Driver =(SQL Server);DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=BUSINESS_BWP;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
   ADOConn.Open

   Debug.Print ADOConn.State

   Dim db As Database
   Set db = CurrentDb

   'db.Execute "INSERT INTO [ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;ENCSQL28\BUSINESS_BWP;DATABASE=CurrentDb].SFTransfersDB ( ID, TO ) SELECT ID,TO FROM SFTransfersDB"

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not run query on the linked table: `INSERT INTO mssql_linked_tbl (...) SELECT ... FROM acc_local_tbl`?

Comment: but you can run those queries against the sql server. Why any need to transfer things back to sql server where  the data already resides?

Comment: Parfait - Thank you. This was the simplest way to accomplish what I needed. I ended up using   DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Dbo_PO_STATUS_ALL_TBL Select * FROM PO_STATUS_ALL_TBL" to just transfer the data to the table I wanted. You win!

Answer (score 0):

I went through this process lately.

For migration you can use [this tool by Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255). With this tool you can either migrate a table or a query to MS-SQL - or even both. Even with relations.

Simple export with this wizard and add your one table through ODBC Connector in Access. Important is to have the correct [ODBC Driver.](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested I resolved this issue with Parfait's advise. By using a simple `INSERT` statement.

```sql
INSERT INTO Dbo_PO_STATUS_ALL_TBL Select * FROM PO_STATUS_ALL_TBL
```